# MSIEXEC uninstall application using GUID with GUI wizard, but no user interaction

Tags: guid, uninstallation, windows-installer

i know how to uninstall MSI package using msiexec by guid:

msiexec /i {ProductCode}

This brings up the uninstall wizard of the application and the user has to click next next next.....finish. i want the uninstall wizard to be shown as normal, but the user should not click next next next on the wizard.... instead, the application should be uninstalled automatically, with GUI wizard, but no user interaction. the wizard should also close automatically after uninstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

msiexec /I {ProductCode} won't initiate an uninstall, it will initiate a maintenance installation transaction (change, repair, remove)

You likely want `msiexec /x {ProductCode} /qb`